# What is the entity in JPA?

Tags: jpa, orm, entity

Somebody asked me, what is the entity?
Unfortunately, I didn't know correctly definition.

First I answered
`Entity is just the class that related by Relational table.`
But I thought that is not whole meaning..

And Second I answered
`Entity is the one that is managed by persistence context.`

And then he asked me,
`So.. The table that created by @ManyToMany relation is entity?`

And then I started to confuse.
What is the entitiy's correct meaning?

And please answer about table that created by @ManyToMany question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JPA specification document](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_2-mrel-eval-spec/index.html) (version 2.2) says it all on page 23:

> An entity is a lightweight **persistent domain object**.

Per se, an `Entity` is just a marker that a a certain *type* can be persisted to some persistence store, typically a (relational) database. It does not define, however, how relationships to other *types* are mapped / expressed within that domain.

In the context of ORM, such domain objects (i.e., instances of a certain *type* in the domain) are mapped to the schema of a database which - in relational databases - is expressed by a set of *Tables*.

For a correct mapping of a *n:m* relationships (`@ManyToMany`), additional structures in the persistence store might be required, typically expressed by an additional table, e.g. `TableA_TableB`. Thus, one can not claim that an entity always corresponds to *one* table exactly, in particular when relationships to other types are needed.

From a bidirectional perspective, tables in a (relational) database can not necessarily be mapped to domain types in the sense that they would exactly represent a *type* of a domain. Or in other words: Tuples/rows in a relational *table* do not necessarily correspond to an instance (object) of a certain *type*. For the background and further details see [*Database Normalization Theory*](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/an-introduction-to-database-normalization/) by Mike Hillyer.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look a the **Java EE tutorial**:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro001.htm#BNBQA

There you will find the definition:

> 7.1 Entities
>
> An entity is a lightweight persistence domain object. Typically, an
>   entity represents a table in a relational database, and each entity
>   instance corresponds to a row in that table. The primary programming
>   artifact of an entity is the entity class, although entities can use
>   helper classes.

Or you could also have a look at the **JPA specification**:

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_2-mrel-eval-spec/index.html

Comment: And stressing "**Typically**, an entity represents a table...".